# What does this linux command do?

Tags: linux, terminal, debian

I was doing the google cloud app engine tutorial and i saw this command. (linux/git).

```
TUTORIALDIR=src/ewbproject-187620/php_gae_quickstart-2017-12-01-10-29
```

What does it do?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

It assigns the value `src/ewbproject-187620/php_gae_quickstart-2017-12-01-10-29` to the variable `$TUTORIALDIR`.

Answer (score 0):

It defines a shell environment variable that will be available during the shell session to be used as arguments for shell commands and programs. For example:

```
$ VAR1='test'
$ echo $VAR1
test
$
```

It is possible to use a environment variables inside a program, but to do that you will need to:

1. use a library that provides access to them as [this one for php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php)
2. use `export VAR1` after defining the environment variable